# PdfCleanUpTool SetRedactionColor

Tags: itext7

Is there a way to use PdfCleanUpTool so that the RedactionColor is transparent (i.e., it çshows the color of the actual background), instead of having to choose one.

Comment: Have you tried setting the clean up color to `null`?

Comment: Yes, and it crashes.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. According to the JavaDocs `null` should do the job... I'll have a look later.

Comment: I just tested using the `PdfCleanUpTool` with a `null` clean up color and it did not crash. I wouldn't be sure, though, that "the color of the actual background" can be seen: Depending on how that background is created, I would expect it to also be redacted.

Comment: I tested now with PdfCleaner.AutoSweepCleanUp(pdfDoc, strategy) and it works! Thanks for the suggestion to use null.

Comment: @argledhel please add your answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but using PdfCleanUpTool.CleanUp() crashed (after adding the locations). However, this did the job (PdfCleaner.AutoSweepCleanUp):

```
    public static void RemoveTexts(PdfDocument pdfDoc, List<Regex> regexes)
    {
        CompositeCleanupStrategy strategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();

        foreach (Regex rgx in regexes)
        {
            RegexBasedCleanupStrategy rbCS = new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(rgx);

            rbCS.SetRedactionColor(null);

            strategy.Add(rbCS);
        }

        PdfCleaner.AutoSweepCleanUp(pdfDoc, strategy);
    }
```